# Do I need to be configured as a publisher to do request/response (full dupllex) between endpoints configured AsA_Server in NServiceBus?

Tags: nservicebus

I am only using `Bus.Reply()` (not `Bus.Publish()`) in my endpoints (all configured `AsA_Server`).  When I fire one of them up, I get the following warning:

`2013-02-27 14:11:02,574 [Worker.15] WARN  NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus [(null)
] <(null)> - Subscription message from [not the currently running endpoint's queue]@my machine arrived at this endpoint, yet this endpoint is not configured to be a publi
sher.`

Do I need to be configured `AsA_Publisher` in order to do request/response between endpoints configured `AsA_Server`?  The full duplex sample does not seem to give any additional guidance in this area.

Answer (score 1):

[Per Andreas Ohlund](https://twitter.com/andreasohlund/status/306855836649664512):

> That's just a warning, turn off auto subscriptions to avoid it.

Code to do this:

`Configure.UnicastBus().DoNotAutoSubscribe();`

Also per Andreas, [AutoSubscription will only apply to `IEvent` messages](https://github.com/NServiceBus/NServiceBus/commit/31345f9281a04c65ff9c77204f3749dc64d580b0).

Comment: Just to clarify: auto sub in 3.x is for all messages except commands. In 4.x it will be all messages that are events